# Pointing SVN workspace to different server & repository with different parent directory

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, migration

I have an svn repository that is slated EOL, and the various projects are being moved through svnrdump dump and svnadmin load to a new repository.  For the purposes of discussion, the basic topology is:

```
old repo:  http://oldrepo/repositories/oldname/...
new repo:  http://newrepo/repositories/newname/...
```

This particular repository is large and I have a developer wishing to point his old workspace to the new repository.  The problem that I am seeing is that TortoiseSVN allow a relocate event, and by entering the URL `http://newrepo/repositories/newname`, the initial relocate seems successful.  However, the workspace now believes the directory structure on the new repo looks like this:

```
http://newrepo/repositories/newname/oldname
```

Is there a way to remove the workspace's reference to oldname?  Because of the extra unintended directory, an SVN update fails.  The only option I can think of is to have this developer checkout the entire needed workspace fresh from the new repository, and have him copy his WIP files into the new workspace.  Are there other options or solutions on the client side?

Edit:  The working directory is c:\SVN\FolderA.  Performing the command: `svn relocate http://newrepo/repositories/newname/Folder1/FolderA` returns the following error:

```
svn: E155024: Invalid relocation destination: 'http://newrepo/repositories/newname/Folder1/FolderA' (does not point to target)
```

I am not sure how relevant this is, but the original repository location oldrepo was a folder, but in the new repository, newrepo (ie: `http://newrepo/repositories/newname`) is the root level for the new repository.  Also, I should point out that during the migration, the changes were preserved but the individual version numbers were not.

Comment: Your developer may have to disconnect his project from the old workspace, delete his project, and export his project from the new workspace.

Comment: I instructed him to do this.  My feeling is that, because the directory structure changed from the old to the new repository, there would be no clean way to point the old workspace to the new repository.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, if you want to put your comment as a formal answer, this is what I've accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your developer will probably have to:

- Disconnect his project from the old workspace
- Save his uncommitted changes (if any) somewhere else
- Delete his project
- Export his project from the new workspace
- Reapply his uncommitted changes (if any) to the project

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with my working copy. This "invalid relocation destination" error might be avoided if the repository UUID was copied to the new repos (using the "svnlook uuid" and "svnadmin setuuid" commands) but when I upgraded my working copy to 1.8, I got this error when trying to relocate my working copy to the new repo.

I suggest that you just remove the hidden .svn folder in the root of your working folder and just perform the checkout again using the new URL to the same folder.  SVN will just "version" the files again for the new repository but it will take just as long as if you had performed a fresh checkout.  If you have any modified file, first create a patch file before you re-checkout to the same folder in case the checkout command overwrites modified files.

Keep in mind there is a difference between the two paths:

```
http://newrepo/repositories/newname
http://newrepo/repositories/newname/ <-- notice the final slash
```

The first path says "copy the newname directory to the target folder" where the second path says "copy the contents of the newname directory to the target folder".

Hope this helps.